# How to generate cisco key-hash string

Tags: cisco, ssh, authentication

cisco IOS stores public keys used for authentication as hashes.
cisco obviously does not store the key itself because you can simply copy these `key-hash` lines between machines and you can authenticate (not sure how the hash is sufficient; but that's a different question).
Normally when one inserts a string into a cisco with the `key-string` command, the machine calculates the hash of the public key string and inserts the hash into the config.

cisco's documentation helpfully says:

> **Note**
> You can use a hashing software to compute the hash of the public key string, or you can also copy the hash value from another Cisco device.

But there is no further info.

How would one calculate that hash outside of a cisco?

Which hashing algorithm do they use?

You can see the sha256 hash of a key (fingerprint) via `ssh-add -l` (if you're using the agent) or `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. However, attempting to use the sha256 string fails in a cisco with: `% SSH: Invalid keyhash data`

EDIT:
by way of example, here is what it looks like after you insert a `key-string` and the IOS converts it to a hash:

```
  username ericx
   key-hash ssh-rsa 9BE0B8907953349DC84C16EE2D59**** ericx@ericx-office2
```

You will note that no hash type info is available (normally displayed as a number for a password). You will also note that there is no way to specify which algorithm the cisco uses. Presumably always the same one.

Comment: There are multiple hashes that could be used. You need to understand which hash is used. That is communicated by a number next to the hash when you `show running-config`, e.g. `5` for a Type 5 hash. Search for `cisco password hash algorithm`.

Comment: @RonMaupin "type" is not displayed for "key-hash" just regular passwords.

Comment: It does not display the word `type`, only the number of the type. For example, you may see `enable secret 5 00271A5307542A02D22842`, where the `5` means it is a Type 5 password hash.

Comment: @RonMaupin These are not passwords. There is no option when entering the data to specify the type. There is no display of the type used. It's a mystery. That, in essence is actually the crux of my question. Which hashing algorithm do they use?

Comment: Cisco SSHv2 uses Triple DES, and it has some specific requirements. You can search the Cisco documentation to get things like _[Secure Shell Configuration Guide, Cisco IOS Release 15E](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_usr_ssh/configuration/15-e/sec-usr-ssh-15-e-book/sec-secure-shell-v2.html)_.

Comment: @RonMaupin 3DES is not a hashing algorithm. It's an encryption algorithm. encryption is reversible (e.g. you can decrypt the contents). A hash is one-way. They serve different purposes.

Comment: You did not read the document I linked in my comment. Keys are RSA generated.

Answer (score 3):

Cisco uses various hashes. Simply search for `cisco password hash algorithm` , and you will find explanations, such as *[Cisco Routers Password Types](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/s/article/cisco-routers-password-types)*:

> ### Cisco Routers Password Types
>
> Feb 13, 2020
>
> Knowledge Yasser Auda Cisco
>
> Routers Password Types:
> -------------------------------------------
> **Type 0**
> this mean the password will not be encrypted when router store it in Run/Start Files
> command:
> **enable password cisco123**
>
> **Type 4**
> this mean the password will be encrypted when router store it
> in Run/Start Files using SHA-256 which apps like Cain can crack but
> will take long time
> command :
> **enable secret 4 Rv4kArhts7yA2xd8BD2YTVbts**
> (notice above is not the password string it self but the hash of the password)
>
> this type is deprecated starting from IOS 15.3(3)
>
> **Type 5**
> this mean the password will be encrypted when router store it
> in Run/Start Files using MD5 which apps like Cain can crack but will
> take long time
> command:
> **enable secret 5 00271A5307542A02D22842**
> (notice above is not the password string it self but the hash of the password)
> or
> **enable secret cisco123**
> (notice above is the password string it self)
>
> **Type 7**
> this mean the password will be encrypted when router store it
> in Run/Start Files using Vigenere cipher which any website with type7
> reverser can crack it in less than one second
> command :
> **ena password cisco123**
> **service password-encryption**
>
> **Type 8**
>
> this mean the password will be encrypted when router store it in
> Run/Start Files using PBKDF2-SHA-256
>
> starting from IOS 15.3(3).
>
> Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2 (PBKDF2) with Secure Hash
> Algorithm, 26-bits (SHA-256) as the hashing algorithm
>
> Example :
>
> R1(config)#**enable algorithm-type sha256 secret cisco**
>
> R1(config)#do sh run | i enable
>
> enable secret 8
> $8$mTj4RZG8N9ZDOk$elY/asfm8kD3iDmkBe3hD2r4xcA/0oWS5V3os.O91u.
>
> Example :
>
> R1(config)# **username yasser algorithm-type sha256 secret cisco**
>
> R1# show running-config | inc username
>
> username yasser secret 8
> $8$dsYGNam3K1SIJO$7nv/35M/qr6t.dVc7UY9zrJDWRVqncHub1PE9UlMQFs
>
> **Type 9**
>
> this mean the password will be encrypted when router store it in
> Run/Start Files using scrypt as the hashing algorithm.
>
> starting from IOS 15.3(3)
>
> Example :
>
> R1(config)#**ena algorithm-type scrypt secret cisco**
>
> R1(config)#do sh run | i enable
>
> enable secret 9
> $9$WnArItcQHW/uuE$x5WTLbu7PbzGDuv0fSwGKS/KURsy5a3WCQckmJp0MbE
>
> Example :
>
> R1(config)# **username demo9 algorithm-type scrypt secret cisco**
>
> R1# show running-config | inc username
>
> username demo9 secret 9
> $9$nhEmQVczB7dqsO$X.HsgL6x1il0RxkOSSvyQYwucySCt7qFm4v7pqCxkKM
>
> **Important Notes:**
>
> 1-If you configure type 8 or type 9 passwords and then downgrade to a
> release that does not support type 8 and type 9 passwords, you must
> configure the type 5 passwords before downgrading. If not, you are
> locked out of the device and a password recovery is required.
>
> 2-Starting from IOS 15.3(3)The 4 keyword was deprecated and support
> for type 8 and type 9 algorithms were added and The warning message
> for removal of support for the type 4 algorithm was added.
>
> Yasser Ramzy Auda Dubai 6-16-2015 version1
>
> Dubai 6-28-2016 version2

You need to know which hashing algorithm is used to be able to recreate the hash. You will also find recommendations as to which has should be used in your network devices, depending on the level of protection you need.

Comment: "type" info is not displayed for cisco key-hash. formatting will mangle in this comment, but here's an example:
ip ssh pubkey-chain
  username j*****
   key-hash ssh-rsa AC22E79C3F54AC3282668BC2E8****** j***@****
   key-hash ssh-rsa 454614E991351D0B7A29D1C32F****** j***@****

Comment: The question was about hashing RSA keys, not passwords. Your lengthy answer is technically correct, but completely irrelevant.